# My commits are deploying changes only once after i clone the repo

Tags: git, deployment, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

Whenever i push a commit it goes to bitbucket but does not make changes on the website. But whenever i delete the repo in sourcetree and reclone it, it makes the changes when i do next commit.

I cant delete and re-clone it every time in sourcetree so please help.

here is the log

```
2014-11-11 10:45:13-08:00 --- INFO: Attempting deployment...
2014-11-11 10:45:13-08:00 --- INFO: Changing working directory... 
2014-11-11 10:45:14-08:00 --- INFO: Reseting repository... HEAD is now at a665bed no message
2014-11-11 10:45:25-08:00 --- INFO: Pulling in changes... HEAD is now at a665bed no message Updating a665bed..94cd5b5 Fast-forward  img/bg_vip.jpg |  Bin 105494 -> 285014 bytes  index.php      |    2 +-  vip/index.php  |    6 +++---  3 files changed, 4 insertions(+), 4 deletions(-)
2014-11-11 10:45:25-08:00 --- INFO: Securing .git directory... 
2014-11-11 10:45:25-08:00 --- INFO: Updating wordpress database... 
2014-11-11 10:45:25-08:00 --- INFO: Deployment successful.
2014-11-11 22:11:24-08:00 --- INFO: Attempting deployment...
2014-11-11 22:11:24-08:00 --- INFO: Changing working directory... 
2014-11-11 22:11:31-08:00 --- INFO: Reseting repository... HEAD is now at 94cd5b5 no message
2014-11-11 22:11:31-08:00 --- INFO: Pulling in changes... HEAD is now at 94cd5b5 no message
2014-11-11 22:11:31-08:00 --- INFO: Securing .git directory... 
2014-11-11 22:11:31-08:00 --- INFO: Updating wordpress database... 
2014-11-11 22:11:31-08:00 --- INFO: Deployment successful.
2014-11-11 22:14:59-08:00 --- INFO: Attempting deployment...
2014-11-11 22:15:00-08:00 --- INFO: Changing working directory... 
2014-11-11 22:15:01-08:00 --- INFO: Reseting repository... HEAD is now at 94cd5b5 no message
2014-11-11 22:15:01-08:00 --- INFO: Pulling in changes... HEAD is now at 94cd5b5 no message
2014-11-11 22:15:01-08:00 --- INFO: Securing .git directory... 
2014-11-11 22:15:03-08:00 --- INFO: Updating wordpress database... 
2014-11-11 22:15:03-08:00 --- INFO: Deployment successful.
2014-11-11 22:17:05-08:00 --- INFO: Attempting deployment...
2014-11-11 22:17:05-08:00 --- INFO: Changing working directory... 
2014-11-11 22:17:06-08:00 --- INFO: Reseting repository... HEAD is now at 94cd5b5 no message
2014-11-11 22:17:06-08:00 --- INFO: Pulling in changes... HEAD is now at 94cd5b5 no message
2014-11-11 22:17:06-08:00 --- INFO: Securing .git directory... 
2014-11-11 22:17:06-08:00 --- INFO: Updating wordpress database... 
2014-11-11 22:17:06-08:00 --- INFO: Deployment successful.
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your BitBucket repository show up when you type `git remote -v`?
When you push, try: `git push origin master`, where `origin` is the name of the remote, and `master` is the name of your branch.